# Reading uploaded csv file into pandas dataframe

Tags: django

I am uploading a CSV file and wish to load it into a pandas dataframe. I have a problem loading the file into my view. The warning message is sent to the template which signifies that the file was not sent to the view.

Here is my view:

```
def showReadUploadedView(request, **kwargs):
    context = {}

    test_file = request.GET.get(u'testFile')
    df = pd.read_csv(test_file)
    context = {'df': df}

   if not test_file:
        messages.warning(request, f'No file to process! Please upload a file to process.')
        return render(request, 'tasks/up_load.html', context)
```

Here is my template:

```
   <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         {% csrf_token %}
         <input type="file" class="form-control-file mt-1 mb-1" id="testFile">

      <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mb-3 mt-1" type="submit">Process this</button>

      <a href="{% url 'upload-task' task.id %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mb-3 mt-1">Process Data</               
   </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the data is being sent by the POST method (as defined on your form), there won't be anything in `request.GET`.  However, since it is a file input, it also won't be in  `request.POST` either. Django handles files specially and puts them in `request.FILES`.

```
def showReadUploadedView(request, **kwargs):
    context = {}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        test_file = request.FILES.get(u'testFile')
        if test_file:
            df = pd.read_csv(test_file)
            context['df'] = df
        else:
            messages.warning(request, f'No file to process! Please upload a file to process.')
    return render(request, 'tasks/up_load.html', context)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/